# why aren't newlines / other control sequences printed with static_assert?

Tags: c++11, string-literals, static-assert

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static_assert(false, R"error(This is an error message.  You need to

1. Pick up the phone.
2. Call GhostBusters.
3. Run and hide.

)error");
}
```

gives

```
error: static_assert failed "This is an error message. You need to\n\n1. Pick up the phone.\n2. Call GhostBusters.\n3. Run and hide.\n\n"
    static_assert(false, err);
    ^             ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Does anybody know the reason these are "unescaped"?  Is it compiler / platform dependent?  Part of the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC gives you the newlines you want: https://godbolt.org/g/jS7Sgm

The exact presentation depends on the compiler.  Printing escape codes or not can probably best be described as a "quality of implementation" issue.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says nothing more than:

> the resulting diagnostic message (4.1) shall include the text of the string-literal, if one is supplied, except that characters not in the basic source character set (5.3) are not required to appear in the diagnostic message.

Newlines are part of the basic source character set, so they are required to "appear". Exactly *how* they appear is not a matter the standard controls.